# send ownership territories Worldwide via Youtube Partner Api

Tags: api, youtube

i m searching worldwide code (all territories include).

{
  "general": 
  [
    {
      "owner": "xxxxx",
      "ratio": 100,
      "territories": 
      ["TR","BR"  (i need worldwide code. should i write all iso code?)
      ],
      "type": "include"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Have you figured this out? I think you should try:

```
type: "exclude", territories: []
```

In other words you are excluding none.